# How would you approach this problem in a timely manner regarding different way to multiply

Tags: factoring

If you had no more than 1-2 minutes, how would you approach this Q:

We have four numbers (a, b, c, d), that will create the following pairs

a*b = 5

a*c = 8

a*d = 10

b*c = 16

b*d = 32

c*d = x

Find x

**EDIT**

Original question pic:

[image]

Comment: Try to calculate $abcd$.

Comment: If I was in a rush I would probably start with $d=2b$ and $d=2c$ so $b=c$

Comment: What does "tamely" mean?

Comment: This problem doesn't work.  By the first 3 equations the ratios of $b:c:d = 5:8:10$.  But by the next two the ratio of $c:d = 16:32$.  Maybe you mistyped something.

Comment: @IanJ I did not mistyped, please see edit with pic of original question

Comment: You appear to be assuming that the products _ab_, _ac_, etc. are in the order given in the question: 5,8,... This is unjustified in my opinion.

Comment: Okay you have got a point, so that's why I made this post, to see how others would approach it.. if you would like to share your method and elaborate

Comment: @IanJ It works if $ad=16$

Comment: @Raffaele.  I was responding to the initial question.  Which is stated badly.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate $abcd$ in three ways from the given numbers:

$$abcd = ad\times bc = ac\times bd = ab\times cd $$

Every number is used exactly once in the above equations, so we must be able to find two pairs of numbers with the same product. In fact, we can do it in two ways:

$$5\times 16=10\times 8=32\times cd\\
5\times 32=10\times 16=8\times cd$$

This gives us the two solutions $cd= 5/2$ and $cd=20$.

There seems to be no reason to prefer one solution more than the other. In fact, with some more time you can find out the possibilities for the four variables themselves to confirm that both solutions are valid. In each case there are two possibilities.

The set $\{2, 5/2, 4, 8\}$ gives products $\{5, 8, 10, 16, 20, 32\}$. An alternative set that gives the same products is $\{ \sqrt{10}/2, \sqrt{10}, 8\sqrt{10}/5, 2\sqrt{10} \}$.

The set $\{ 5/4, 2, 4, 8\}$ gives products $\{5/2, 5, 8, 10, 16, 32\}$. An alternative set that gives the same products is
$\{ \sqrt{5}/2, \sqrt{5}, 2\sqrt{5}, 16\sqrt{5}/5 \}$.

Comment: But this system is *impossible* $$\{a b,a c,a d,b c,b d\}=\{5,8,10,16,32\}$$

Comment: @Raffaele: No. $(ab,ac,ad,bc,bd)=(5,8,10,16,32)$ is impossible, but the assignment of the numbers does not have to be in that order according to the original question in the image. This was pointed out by Michael Cohen in the comments.

Comment: I mean $abcd$ can be $256$ or $160$. Impossible.

Comment: AWWWW! So OP wrote it wrong and never edited... surely if they are like this they will never solve problems in 1-2 minutes. LOL!

Comment: @Raffaele My first solution has $(ab,ac,ad,bc,bd)=(8,5,16,10,32)$, with $abcd=160$.